# Add active class without any click or pressing any key(checkbox)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, checkbox

I want the checkbox field should add an active class to its label if it is checked. I have done everything like when check it adds class to label and when not checked it does not add the active class.

But my point is when the code is

`<label class="define--area--label"><input type="checkbox" checked ><label>`

then it does not add the active class to the label.

here is my code

```
 $('.define--area--label > input').change(function() {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            $(this).parent().addClass('active');
        } else {
            $(this).parent().removeClass('active');
        }

    });
```

[Full Example](http://jsfiddle.net/34q417Ls/)

Comment: where class '.define--area--label' is defined in HTML code?

Comment: now i have added that..You can also  visit the example page

Comment: it's working properly in Chrome latest version

Comment: just tested it on IE and FF also working as it should be

Comment: Yeah its working everywhere but i was unable to do it automatically but you can find the below answer where i got the solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have to trigger change event through JavaScript after document loaded.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.define--area--label > input').change(function() {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            $(this).parent().addClass('active');
        } else {
            $(this).parent().removeClass('active');
        }

    });
   $('.define--area--label > input:checked').trigger('change');
})
```

Comment: you can use either change or click event

Comment: hey you thank you so much, Exactly this is what i was looking for,, Thank you soo soo much.. I've learned something ...Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
    $('.define--area--label > input').each(function() {
        if($(this).is(':checked')){
            $(this).parent().addClass('active');
        }
    });
});
```